# MySQL connection pool. Сколько соединений открывать?

Tags: mysql, node.js, connection-pool

Есть куча информации как использовать connection pool, но так и не нашел информации от чего отталкиваться при выборе открытых соединений. 1 соединение на ядро? Или зависит от настроек конфигурации самой базы данных (в моём случае MySQL)? Зависит ли от языка программирования(в моём случае nodejs)? Как подобрать оптимальное количество заранее открытых соединений к БД?

Comment: Соединения открываются быстро, так что открывать по мере необходимости. Основная зависимость - от реальной нагрузки. Если основная обработка идет в БД, то количество соединений к БД может быть равна количеству параллельно работающих обработчиков http запросов. А если помимо БД скрипт сам много процессора или других ресурсов использует, то возможно пул будет меньше, потому что меньше необходимость в одновременно выполняющихся запросах

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от настроек MySQL. По умолчанию в MySQL 5.5 максимальное количество одновременно открытых клиентских соединений 100, это можно посмотреть через скрипт:

```
mysql> show variables like 'max_connections';
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| max_connections | 100   |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Можно конечно и увеличить, но не советую. Количество коннектов - это ценный ресурс, требующий довольно памяти/места.

Для пула, мне кажется, достаточно держать 10 соединений, надо же оставить остальным клиентам тоже что-то

Comment: А будет ли существенная разница в нагрузке на процессор при 10 и при 100 соединениях? А так же интересно, разве 1 соединение занимает много памяти? И еще вопрос, кажется я видел открытые соединения к MySQL не от моего приложения, это какие то внутренние служебные соединения, и на них тоже распространяется общее число max_connections?

Comment: @Евгений это все словесные упражнения, все сильно зависит от конфигурации сервера, от окружения и проч. деталей - есть утилита [MySQLTuner](http://blog.mysqltuner.com/download/) - все вопросы/запросы туда.

Comment: спасибо, не слышал о MySQLTuner, думаю он ответит на многие вопросы.